# SQL Server: join tables and duplicate data under certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say we have two tables:

Rooms:

```
Id          RoomNumber
----------- ----------
1           101
2           102
3           201
4           202
```

Reservations:

```
Id          RoomId      StartDate  EndDate
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
1           1           2021-06-01 2021-07-01
2           2           2021-06-01 2021-06-25
3           3           2021-06-01 NULL
```

The result set should show a combination of all rooms and reservations, but also a duplicate 'dummy' row for the rooms that are not under reservation TODAY (2021-06-30):

```
Id          RoomNumber ReservationId StartDate  EndDate
----------- ---------- -----------   ---------- ----------
1           101        1             2021-06-01 2021-07-01
2           102        2             2021-06-01 2021-06-25
3           201        3             2021-06-01 NULL
4           202        NULL          NULL       NULL
2           102        NULL          NULL       NULL
```

A simple left join would of course not include the last row. I've tried several things, but I'm starting to feel I'm looking too far...

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

I've come up with this, but could there be another out of the box solution?

```
SELECT rooms.id AS RoomId
    ,rooms.RoomNumber
    ,reservations.id AS ReservationId
    ,reservations.StartDate
    ,reservations.EndDate
FROM 
    rooms
LEFT JOIN 
    reservations ON rooms.id = reservations.roomid

UNION

SELECT r1.id AS RoomId
    ,r1.RoomNumber
    ,NULL AS ReservationId
    ,NULL AS StartDate
    ,NULL AS EndDate
FROM
    rooms r1
RIGHT JOIN 
    reservations res1 ON r1.id = res1.roomid
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT rooms.*
     FROM rooms
     INNER JOIN reservations res2 ON rooms.id = res2.roomid
     WHERE ENDDATE IS NULL) r2 ON r1.id = r2.id
WHERE 
    ENDDATE < Convert(DATE, GetDate())
```

Comment: you want to select from Room and LEFT JOIN on reservations. Then you could union with a where clause with EndDate>=GETDATE()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way:

> ```
> select r.id, roomnumber,rv.id as ReservationId , startDate,EndDate from room r
> join reservations rv
> on r.id = rv.roomId
> union all 
>
> select Id,roomnumber, null, null ,null 
> from room r
> where not exists (select 1 from reservations rv 
>                  where r.id = rv.roomId 
>                  and getdate() between startDate and isnull(EndDate, dateadd(day , 1 ,getdate()))
>                 )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | roomnumber | ReservationId | startDate  | EndDate   
> -: | ---------: | ------------: | :--------- | :---------
>  1 |        101 |             1 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-07-01
>  2 |        102 |             2 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-06-25
>  3 |        201 |             3 | 2021-06-01 | null      
>  2 |        102 |          null | null       | null      
>  4 |        202 |          null | null       | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efed43dfa02feb8cfad1af53d69bc9ad)*